# How to send the data (BLOB & CLOB) to the database from java

Tags: java, mysql

The table columns have the data type BLOB and CLOB.

What are the corresponding Java data types?

I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLOB and CLOB are bytes strings stored in database.

In MySQL, you can have an entity with a field of byte array representing your BLOB / CLOB.

E.g.

```
class MyBlob implements Serializable {

  byte[] myBlobField;

  //Setter
  public void setMyBlobField(byte[] myBlobField) {
    this.myBlobField = myBlobField;
  }

  //Getter
  public byte[] getMyBlobField() {
     return myBlobField;
  }
}
```

On JDBC, create a `PreparedStatement` and do something of this effect:

```
 MyBlob blob = ....;
 PreparedStatement ps = ....;
 ps.setByte(1, blob.getMyBlobField());

 ps.execute();
 //Handle Exceptions...close...etc.
```

Comment: I have to send an array of blob as parameter to stored procedures in java. How can i do that ??